# Trend duration in Excel

Tags: excel

Suppose I want to tell Excel:

`if A2<x count following cells (A2, A3, ...) until  <x  is not satisfied anymore and print the number of consecutive cells in which the condition is satisfied; else print 0.`

(where x is a user-defined constant).

How can I code this?

Comment: so is Column A always sorted ascending?

Comment: No, why? It is a time series of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place *x* in **A1** and in another cell enter:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:A9999>=A1,0),)-1
```

[image]

In this example *x* is *10* and there are 6 consecutive cells starting with **A2** that have values below *10*.  So the counting stops when row#8 is encountered because the value in **A8** is not less than the value in **A1**.

To force *0* if **all** values are below the limit, use:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:A9999>=A1,0),)-1,0)
```

Comment: Ok, but what if there are more consecutive sequences? E.g. 2 3 4 5 6 7 10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 4 5 4 3 5 10 4 5 6 10. In this case I would like to have printed 6, 13, and 3.

Comment: @GiacomoFalchetta  Your posted question indicated that you wanted the counting to stop counting as soon as **<x** was not satisfied.  Therefore everything below row #8 *(in my example)* is ignored.

Comment: Ok, that's true. Thanks! But what if I want to do this for a long sequence where there are multiple sequences that satisfy the condition?